# Advice for a good sitemap structure

Tags: sitemap

Who can me explain sitemaps? I am interested in the more complexed structure.

For example: on the homepage I have hyperlink to a page with categories A category can have a subcategory or a product.

The url structure look like this

- Level 0: https://www.example.com/
- Level 1: https://www.example.com/categories
- Level 2: https://www.example.com/categories/subcategories
- Level 2: https://www.example.com/categories/product1
  And so one.

What is a good structure for the sitemap?

I know the structure of a simple sitemap. But it are many urls...

Do I create an index sitemap with and split up everything like a sitemap for the homepage One sitemap for the categories and one for the products?

Comment: What extra data do you want to see from your sitemaps?   Do you want to see how many of your product and category pages are indexed as separate stats?

Comment: No what I want to know is do you add all urls into one sitemap or is it wisely to create a better structured sitemap and search engines understand my site better

Comment: What do you mean by "understand your site better?"  Google will prefer URLs that are in your sitemaps when it finds duplicate content on different URLs on your site, but beyond that I've never heard of search engines using them in any way to understand your site.  Do you have a reference you can share where you heard this?